# NiFi - Call Redis Commands in Groovy Script

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

I am trying to connect to my `Redis` instance from a groovy script (`ExecuteGroovyScript`) and execute arbitrary commands such as `LPUSH`. I currently have `RedisConnectionPoolService` enabled and working fine for caching processors.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any examples are appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I got to the point where I can call a command but for some reason it fails, here is the code and error

[image]

```
service = context.getControllerServiceLookup().getControllerService("2b841623-35ed-1e1a-0a77-46087267939d")
service.getConnection().withCloseable { redis ->
   redis.listCommands().lPush("key".getBytes(), "1".getBytes())
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `RedisConnectionPoolService` called `service` and call `service.getConnection()`, you will have a Spring Redis `RedisConnection` instance, so you can check their API for the kinds of calls you can make.

For `LPUSH` specifically you can call `service.getConnection().listCommands().lpush()`

Comment: Thanks! Could you please take look at my edit? I am able to call functions but they keep failing due to various type errors. Any ideas?

Comment: There should be a stack trace in `logs/nifi-app.log` that should give you more information about the error